# Is it faster to shuffle a list or generate it randomly?

Tags: java, list, sorting, random, shuffle

For use in profiling sorting algorithms, I want an `ArrayList<Integer>` with one million <strike>dollars</strike> integers. The bounds of the integers do not matter: [0, `MAX_VALUE`], [`MIN_VALUE`, `MAX_VALUE`], etc. are all fine, but I do want them to be broadly distributed.

I notice that when I use this code:

```
for (int i=0; i<1_000_000; i++) {
    list.add(i);
}
Collections.shuffle(list);
mergeSorter.sort(list);
```

The `shuffle` call takes about ten seconds to execute, while merge sort takes only 2 milliseconds.

Thus, my question: **would it be faster to generate these numbers randomly (`list.add((int) (Math.random() * 1_000_000))`) than to use `shuffle`, and why?**

(I would profile this myself but my home hardware isn't sufficient to test this out. In addition, I'd like a conceptual/theoretical explanation.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Collections.shuffle()` uses `Random` under the hood.

```
public static void shuffle(List<?> list, Random rnd) {
    int size = list.size();
    if (size < SHUFFLE_THRESHOLD || list instanceof RandomAccess) {
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(list, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));
    } else {
        Object arr[] = list.toArray();

        // Shuffle array
        for (int i=size; i>1; i--)
            swap(arr, i-1, rnd.nextInt(i));

        // Dump array back into list
        ListIterator it = list.listIterator();
        for (int i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
            it.next();
            it.set(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

If you look closely, **two** loops are executed.

- One for creating the new array
- One for updating the list.

If you do this yourself, you can do away with the *second* loop and let *GC* collect the *List*. And if you have an array to begin with you don't even need to create a new copy.

So yes, doing it yourself will increase the performance, but the time complexity will still be *O(n)*

Comment: Thanks for explaining *why* and noticing the complexity constance.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it be faster to generate these numbers randomly `(list.add((int) (Math.random() * 1_000_000)))` than to use shuffle, and why?

It is faster to generate the numbers like that, but you'd get a different result!

- If you shuffle a list of numbers 0 to N-1, you get a list with no duplicates.
- If you generate a lost of N random numbers in the range 0 to N-1, you will *probably* get a list with duplicates.

---

If generating N random numbers is OK, then that will definitely be faster than shuffling.  As you can see from the code, the best-case version of `shuffle` involves generating N random numbers AND performing N swaps.

---

> The shuffle call takes about ten seconds to execute, while merge sort takes only 2 milliseconds.

I'm not sure why you are comparing shuffle and mergesort (or what merge sorter you are using!) but I suspect that the discrepancy is more to do with the way you have coded the benchmarks than anything else.  (It looks like you may not have allowed for JVM warmup effects.)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the duplicates issue, but it's okay either way for my purposes.